# How to add to array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to add some new values to array by doing something similar.

```
$array = array();
$array[7] = 'test1';
$array[7] = 'test2';
```

The problem is that [7] only takes the last value that was added and not test1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a new (sub)array at the desired offset, and use `[]` to append new elements to it:

```
$array = array();
$array[7] = array();
$array[7][] = 'test1';
$array[7][] = 'test2';
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can that be achieved from a foreach loop where [7] is added dynamically? For example. I am displaying the results from a database. There will be multiple [7] and [4] and so on.

Comment: if you're looping through an array of rows, something like `$array[$i][] = 'blahblah';` is that what you mean? I'm a bit confused...

Comment: nvm. I have it sorted out. Thanks for the help.